# Changing how many tick labels on a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 3 arrays,

```
y = [1,4,6,8,2,5,......];
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,......];
xlabel = {'label1','label2','label3',........};
```

where each element in xlabel is the label for each element of the x array.

I am plotting this using:

```
plot(x,y);
set(gca,'xtick',x,'xticklabel',xlabel);
```

But because my arrays hold thousands of elements I am getting a black bar as a label because MATLAB is printing every label (see image).

[image: Note different data is used that has been povided]

How do I change this so MATLAB only prints a select few of my xlabels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do for example:

```
selected = 1:100:numel(x); % change the "100" as desired
set(gca,'xtick',x(selected),'xticklabel',xlabel(selected));
```

Comment: This is great thanks. Is there anyway i can make it automatically update when i use the zoom feature on the figure?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you could overload the `zoom` function, but that may not be easy. A better alternative is to register a function to be executed when you click the in the are covered by the axes. For that you use the property `ButtonDownFunction` of the axes. That function could for example divide the current axes into ten parts and set the ticks and labels